# Linux stuck one hour ahead (CentOS)

Tags: centos, time-zone

I use CentOS, and for some reason, one of the servers I bought (amongst a network of other servers I do not own) is off by one hour. The time is one hour ahead no matter what time zone I set it to.

```
[root@adventurelobbies5 ~]# mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.bak
[root@adventurelobbies5 ~]# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
[root@adventurelobbies5 ~]# date
Mon May 14 18:24:23 EDT 2012
```

Right now, it's actually `Mon May 14 17:24:23 EDT 2012`

Any ideas? I've heard things about setting the hardware clock? I'm not sure if I have access to that as this is a VPS.

Comment: Have you issued a `ntpdate` to a public ntp server?

Comment: @ChristopheD Not sure I am following.

Comment: you use ntpdate to pull time off of an ntp server

Comment: I don't have permission to run it.

Comment: if you are root, you should have permission to run ntpdate unless its not installed.  You can also manually set the date/time via 'date +%T -s "17:24:23"' as root, but ntpdate is better to sync with a time server.

Comment: @ChristopheD Why don't you leave an answer that explains the situation? Clearly Gray is looking for any info, so just tell him what you'd do to improve the situation and why you think it would work.